# Как реализовать сохранение двумерного массива при завершении программы на android?

Tags: android, android-studio

Мне надо сохранить данные формата

```
"5555555555-0;
 6666666666-2;
 7777777777-1;"
```

и т.д.

Данных не много. Потом надо при запуске их считать в переменные.
Думал сделать запись сплошной строкой в Shared Preferences и потом при запуске разбивать по разделителям "-" и ";". Но мне кажется, должен быть способ поэффективнее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, еще хоть какой-нибудь вариант. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нормальный способ… не выдумывай. Если даных не много…

Comment: Или просто в константы сохранить.

Comment: Мне даже строки разбивать не пришлось - первая часть будет ключом, а вторая значением.

Answer (score 0):

А я бы, наверное, в базу данных сохранял. Просто пока непонятно, для чего именно это будет применяться.